# Loop coordinates into string repeated len(x) times

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a DataFrame filled with lat and lng coordinates like so:

```
     lat        lng
0   -33.859485  151.208584
1   -33.868370  151.207141
2   -33.861735  151.210873
```

Googlemaps uses the following string to place markers on a map, which I will call new_marker:

```
new_marker = '&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7C'+str(lat)+'+'+str(lng)
```

How could I create a loop which creates a string where `new_marker` is repeated `x` times (`x` in this case being the number of coordinates in the dataframe), with each repeat having the respective `lat` and `lng` inputted from the dataframe?

In effect, I'd like to be able to generate something like this:

`'&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7C+lat0+lng0&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7C+lat1_lng1&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7C+lat2+lng2'`

My experience with `for` and `def` is very limited.

Comment: do you want to create a new column with the corresponding string for lat and lng? Or a single string with all the coordinates?

Comment: a single string, answered using second method below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string corresponding to each lat and lng can be easily created with pandas [apply method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) combined with [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/).

The first step is to define the function that given a row, generates the desired string:

```
def coord_formatter(row):
    return '&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7C{:.6f}+{:.6f}'.format(row['lat'],row['lng'])
```

This basically substitutes `row['lat']` to the position in the string where there is the `{:.6f}`, formatted as a 6 decimal position float, and the lng to the second.

Then, the new column can be created:

```
df['string'] = df.apply(coord_formatter,axis=1)
# Output df
#          lat         lng                                             string
# 0 -33.859485  151.208584  &markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7...
# 1 -33.868370  151.207141  &markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7...
# 2 -33.861735  151.210873  &markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7...
```

Or, to create a single string:

```
output = '\n'.join(df.apply(coord_formatter,axis=1))
# print(output) produces
# &markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7C-33.859485+151.208584
# &markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7C-33.868370+151.207141
# &markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x0000b3%7Clabel:G%7C-33.861735+151.210873
```

Now each coordinate string is separated with a breakline between them, to have a single string where all of them are simply concatenated, `''.join(...` can be used instead.